# Getting Mongoose ObjectId from String

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, objectid

I am trying to convert a `String` to `ObjectId`:

```
  var _id=mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.notebook);
```

The notebook value is actually the id of a document in the `database`:

```
> db.notebook.findOne()
{
    "title" : "My Notebook",
    "isActive" : false,
    "_id" : ObjectId("54505ced1fa5b1b519bdfc88"),
    "notes" : [ ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I was debugging and the method looked like this:

```
  mongoose.types.ObjectId("54505ced1fa5b1b519bdfc");
```

I got an error to this effect while debugging:

```
 ObjectId must either be a 12 byte string or 24 hex charecters.
```

This error occurs from the method `ObjectId.isValid`.I have tried casting using:

```
 mongoose.Types.ObjectId.fromString(req.body.notebook);
```

and

```
 mongoose.mongo.BSONPure.ObjectID.fromString(req.body.notebook);
```

I understand that I have to convert this string to an appropriate hex format.How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"54505ced1fa5b1b519bdfc" - is only 22 characters long. It's incomplete.